# Running gdb in Debian docker image results

Tags: docker, debugging, gdb, remote-debugging, lego-mindstorms-ev3

I have some trouble when running gdb in a docker image and I am not sure what is causing the problems since I am a complete newbie when it comes to gdb and docker.

#### Background

I am trying to write a c++ program for the Lego EV3 which runs on [ev3dev](http://ev3dev.org). In order to compile it, I have set up docker with the ev3dev image on my Windows machine and am able to successfully build inside that image, transfer the binary to the EV3 and execute it there. This all works well until I need to start (remote) debugging. My plan is to start a gdbserver on the EV3 with the program and the open a gdb session inside the docker container in my Windows machine and connect to the EV3 gdbserver. After I have fixed the first error when remote debugging - I needed to use gdb-multiarch on my Windows machine - I have encountered more problems which I don't really find a solution too.

#### Problem

When running gdb directly on my Windows machine inside the docker container (or when connecting to the gdbserver from docker using gdb-multiarch) I always get the following output after starting the program with `run`:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /src/ev3/build/src/EV3_main
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint -1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x4f58
```

and when using `next` or `step` I get:

```
(gdb) next
Cannot find bounds of current function
```

Since I couldn't really find any solution online, I would really appreciate any help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I always get the following output after starting the program with run

This error usually means that the dynamic loader in your docker container has been fully stripped. It's a packaging mistake by the creator of that container.

If you are not using `dlopen()`, this isn't a big problem.

> `(gdb) next`

Don't do *that*: you are not stopped in a location where GDB knows where the next line is. Do `continue` instead.